# DrRacket and Recursive Statement Binary to Decimal

Tags: recursion, racket

I am trying to convert a binary number entered as "1010" for 10 using recursion. I can't seem to wrap my head around the syntax for getting this to work.

```scm
(define (mod N M)
  (modulo N M))

(define (binaryToDecimal b)
  (let ([s 0])
    (helper b s)))

(define (helper b s)
  (if (= b 0)
      (begin (+ s 0))
      (begin (* + (mod b 2) (expt 2 s) helper((/ b 10) + s 1)))))
```

Thanks!

Comment: (+ s 0) is sort of like s isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple recursive solution:

```scm
(define (bin->dec n)
  (if (zero? n)
      n
      (+ (modulo n 10) (* 2 (bin->dec (quotient n 10))))))
```

testing:

```scm
> (bin->dec 1010)
10
> (bin->dec 101)
5
> (bin->dec 10000)
16
```

Comment: Simple as it should be. I prefer this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `"1010"` to translate to `10` (or `#b1010`, `#o12` or `#xa`) you implement `string->number`

```scm
(define (string->number str radix)
  (let loop ((acc 0) (n (string->list str)))
    (if (null? n)
        acc
        (loop (+ (* acc radix)
                 (let ((a (car n)))
                   (- (char->integer a)
                      (cond ((char<=? a #\9) 48)     ; [#\0-#\9] => [0-9]
                            ((char<?  a #\a) 55)     ; [#\A-#\Z] => [10-36]
                            (else            87))))) ; [#\a-#\z] => [10-36]
              (cdr n)))))

(eqv? #xAAF (string->number "aAf" 16)) ; ==> #t
```

It processes the highest number first and everytime a new digit is processed it multiplies the accumulated value with radix and add the new "ones" until there are not more chars. If you enter `"1010"` and 2 the accumulated value from beginning to end is `0, 0*2+1, 1*2+0, 2*2+1, 5*2+0` which eventually would make sure the digits numbered from right to left 0..n becomes `Sum(vn*radic^n)`

Now, if you need a procedure that only does base 2, then make a wrapper:

```scm
(define (binstr->number n)
  (string->number n 2))

(eqv? (binstr->number "1010") #b1010) ; ==> #t
```

Comment: But, why would you implement `string->number` by hand, when it's built-in to Scheme?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I could have called it `binstr->number` and made it specific but since I would have used `string->number` I though I could implement that instead. Felt just like implementing `length` and `list` when learning Scheme. Also I'm planning a compiler and this isn't the hard part, but perhaps implementing `read` with `read-char` is :-)